# mergecap fails to create output file when run from crontab

Tags: linux, bash, wireshark

I have created a script to merge pcap files using 'mergecap -w '. The script doesn't work as the output file is not already present. So I tried to use 'touch outputfile.pcap' before the mergecap command. But that doesn't create an empty pcap file. All it creates is a temporary file with gibberish on its filename. How will I solve this issue??

Comment: If something works from a terminal but doesn't work through cron, the issue is almost always a difference in environment. Is the working directory, path, user security context etc. what you expect? You can make a short script that does things like `whoami`/`id`, `pwd`, `echo $PATH` and so on to test it.

Comment: I tried that, and simple  script seems to work, its just this script thats not running.  The "mergecap -w "Merge_${TAG1}".pcap ${FILES[@]}"  command fails to run on crontab and syslog says a mail is sent

Comment: Well, I'd expect neither `$TAG1` nor `$FILES` to be populated within crontab, and `$PATH` might be different when running through cron.